# How to make the login shell xterm use utf-8?

Tags: xterm, unicode

I use *xterm* (X-Win32 2012 Build 30 from StarNet Communications Corp) to login from a Windows 7 PC to a Red Enterprise Linux 6 (RHEL6).

My problem is that all multi-byte utf-8 characters comes out garbled in the xterm login shell. For example, here's how the string "Wilhelm Röntgen" is rendered in the two shell instances (the font used is a Unicode font and is the same font in both shell instances):

```
 Login shell: Wilhelm RÃ¶ntgen
 Second shell: Wilhelm Röntgen
```

If I've understood things correctly the software from rom StarNet Communications Corp implements (or emulates) a X terminal (a thin client that runs a X server).  I.e. both shell instances runs in a X terminal window on the PC, and communicates with RHEL6 using the X11 protocol.  Below is how both shells appear on my desktop, catenating a file with unicode multibye characters to the terminal.

[image]

Here is the command I've configured  X-Win32 to use to start the login shell:

```
xterm -u8 -ls
```

However, *after* I login, I can do `xterm` in the login shell, and that command that will fork a new xterm instance where locale setting works as expected (i.e. utf-8 characters are rendered correctly).

Here is the relevant settings as they appear in the login shell:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ printenv XTERM_LOCALE
en_US.UTF-8
```

I also have the following two lines in .Xresources:

```
xterm*locale: true
xterm*utf8: 1
```

It looks like the login shell xterm doesn't recognise the locale I've set, but I don't understand why not.  My xterm is clearly capable of this, since all non-login shells do this by default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the time the sshd process on the remote computer forks to run /usr/bin/xterm there are very few environment variable set. In fact the LANG variable is not set. Hence the xterm process does not know that it should display characters in UTF-8. It falls back to xterms defaults. Whatever that might be.

However, the subshell running inside the xterm runs all setup scripts and alike.
Including setting the LANG environment variable.

One needs to understand the difference between the remote xterm process and the shell process running inside of xterm.

The solution is to run the remote xterm process like this:

```
/usr/bin/env LANG=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/xterm
```

env(1) is a utility to run a program in a modified environment.

Setting LANG will make the remote xterm display UTF-8 characters properly.

Eskil...
:-)

P.s: Reading the xterm manual page I also found an easier way to achieve this:

`xterm -en en_US.UTF-8`

P.P.s: I do not think setting resources in ~/.Xresources will take effect unless you merge them in with xrdb. The xterm process on the Linux computer will query the X server running on your windows computer. At the time where xterm starts it is very unlikely that your X-Win32 server has the xterm* resources set. But you might be able to set resources in X-Win32 if it supports that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not telling `xterm` to use a Unicode font. I see that you're using some xterm-compiled-for-Windows or something, but under Arch (and other distros) when running a *real* xterm, I start it like this:

```
xterm -u8 -fn '-misc-fixed-bold-r-normal--15-140-75-75-c-90-iso10646-1'
```

Another Windows terminal emulator, [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), seems pretty good at showing UTF-8. If you are allowed, you should put PuTTY, set it to use a UTF-8 character set, and connect to the Red Hat server. If PuTTY correctly renders multi-byte UTF-8 characters, you know the problem is not on the server side, but rather in the terminal emulator.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It is not the font (good suggestion tho' - I've expanded the question to cover this angle).  However, PuTTY does it right - so it seems to be the terminal emulator that causes it.  Just weird that the same terminal emulator gets it right when I fork a second shell.  I guess the solution is to ditch the commercial product and go with PuTTY.  However, the StarNet Comm. Corp. *xterm* emulator has some other properties I need.

Comment: If you can run xterm from the shell that runs inside the X-Win32 xterm, aren't you actually runnning an xterm process on the RHEL server, and displaying it on your laptop or desktop? That would be a totally different xterm executable, running on a different machine.

Comment: I don't think *any* xterm process is ever running on the RHEL server.  When I type in `xterm` in the shell on RHEL, all it does is to send a message to the X windows server on the PC, requesting that it creates another xterm process/window. The X-Win32 from StarNet Comm. Corp. turns my PC into a X terminal, and *both* xterm instances executes on the PC, using the X.11 protocol to communicate with the ssh instances on RHEL6.  At least, that is the way I believe X11 works.

Comment: When you type `xterm` in the shell on the RHEL server, a program (maybe `/usr/X11R6/bin/xterm`) runs on RHEL server. Via the magic of the DISPLAY environment variable, all X11 messages go back to the X11 server on your PC. I'm not sure how fonts play into this, whether the X11 server on your PC uses/needs them, or the `xterm` client on RHEL uses or needs them.

Comment: `locale charmap` gives the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The question and followup comments indicate some confusion.  According to StarNet's knowledgebase article *[Where is My Terminal Emulator?](https://www.starnet.com/xwin32kb/where-is-my-terminal-emulator/)*

> X-Win32 is an X Server which main purpose is to display remote graphical applications. Most modern Unix/Linux systems have an X based terminal emulator included in the X libraries. As such X-Win32 does not include one by default.

A comment added to the question by @bruce-ediger states that

> I don't think any xterm process is ever running on the RHEL server. **`When I type in xterm in the shell on RHEL, all it does is to send a message to the X windows server on the PC, requesting that it creates another xterm process/window.`** The X-Win32 from StarNet Comm. Corp. turns my PC into a X terminal, and both xterm instances executes on the PC, using the X.11 protocol to communicate with the ssh instances on RHEL6. At least, that is the way I believe X11 works.

But that is not the way it works.  The xterm process started on the RHEL server runs **on** that server.  It communicates with the StarNet X server (X-Win32), but the xterm process stays where it was started.

The simplest way to start xterm using UTF-8 is via the **`uxterm`** script (which is part of the same package that includes **`xterm`** and its resource-files).  According to the [xterm FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#uxterm_man) describing **`uxterm`**:

> **XTerm** does not automatically set your locale. It can be told to use your locale settings. This is a shell script which sets xterm's resources to use UTF-8 encoding, and use UTF-8 fonts. There is a similar **`lxterm`** script, but it relies upon non-portable applications, unlike **`uxterm`**.

As noted in other comments, your environment variables on login may not have enough information to start **`xterm`** automatically with UTF-8 encoding (and fonts).  That is done by the **`uxterm`** script.

Comment: TLDR my comment: xterm -> uxterm. ---- Full comment: Sorry, didnt read the background yet (will soon), but your idea of simply launching uxterm instead did it for me.
I accidentally, just in time, saw my cyrillic chars were silently(!!) replaced with '#' by xterm, launching a new uxterm solves this (using emacs inside the uxterm). 
Dont forget to replace all scripts and/or alias xterm to uxterm
-- THANKS!!!, the cyrillic stuff is a persons name i get inspired by, she's adding a lot to a character in a book i'm writing (writing a book is such a great hobby:) ).