# Unable to use correctly Powerline with xterm

Tags: fonts, xterm, unicode

I am trying to set up Powerline in my xterm. Im running ArchLinux.
I have followed the steps from [here](http://www.tecmint.com/powerline-adds-powerful-statuslines-and-prompts-to-vim-and-bash/) and I am at this point here:
[image]
So basicaly it works but I just cannot make the arrows appear. This has something to do with the fonts, but I have installed PowerlineSymbols as described in the link above. How can I make the symbols display correctly in xterm?

Comment: I guess it's about correct utf8 handling. This can give you a clue:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116404/how-to-make-the-login-shell-xterm-use-utf-8

Comment: Does it work in other terminal emulators?

Comment: No it does not work...

Comment: I have the very same issue with zsh inside an uxterm, but it works fine in libvte-based terminals. So correct utf8 handling might be required but is not sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this also for a while. What help with me was installing this:

https://github.com/powerline/fonts

And adding the line

```
XTerm*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline
```

into ~/.Xresources.

After that:

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

And then reopening xterm.

Answer (score 3):

I answered this in *[Unable to configure font in XTerm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809617/unable-to-configure-font-in-xterm)*; the place to start is to use the `-fa` option (TrueType fonts) rather than `-fn` (bitmap fonts).

If you are having trouble getting the *font* to display, the `xfd` program is useful, since it accepts an `-fa` option (like `xterm`).  fontconfig will silently replace your font with something that "works" if it is unable to load the font you requested.

With `xfd`:

```
xfd -fa "Powerline Symbols:size=10:antialias=false"
```

Comment: I tried to start xterm with this:  `xterm -fn 7x13 -fa "Powerline Symbols:size=10:antialias=false"`, but still the same result.

Comment: No, this is not necessarily related to vector vs bitmap fonts. [According to the powerline documentation bitmap fonts are supported as well](http://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/master/troubleshooting/linux.html#i-cant-see-any-fancy-symbols-whats-wrong).

Comment: Perhaps, but the guide that OP followed did not use bitmap fonts.