# Xterm does not display unicode character

Tags: fonts, unicode, xterm

Fellow people of the internet,

I got an issue with Xterm, as i try to use a zsh theme using unicode characters. However, Xterm refuses to print them, which is a bit annoying. My Xressources is a followed :

```
hereXTerm*reverseVideo: on
xterm.vt100*FaceName:   hack
XTerm*FaceSize:         15
```

My locale is set to "C", for all of it, i guess the issue comes from here, but i surprisingly don't find a way to set it to en_US.UTF-8, even if it is the only uncommented line in my locale.conf. We are talking basically any unicode character, for instance ❌, which is translated into # followed by 2 blanks.

.
My command line basically looks like this :
[image: My terminal state, when is supposed the a is supposed to be ❌, and the 'i ' are supposed to be arrows]

While it is supposed to look like this :[image]

If it can be of any help, i'm running the latest version of arch.

EDIT: Updating to UTF-8 doesn't solve the issue.

Is there any chance one of you have a solution ?
Thanks

Comment: And when you `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and then start `xterm`?

Comment: Well i'm afraid it changes nothing.

Comment: What kind of character are we talking about?

Comment: Be more specific, edit question and insert screenshot

Comment: Any, ❌ for instance. The thing is i am using compatible fonts, but xterm refuses to recognize the character nonetheless. On my way for an update

Comment: Do you have installed [powerline fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts)?

Comment: Yes i do, hack is one of these

Comment: What is the output of `locale charmap`? How come your distro was not utf-8 ready from the beginning?

Comment: locale charmap output :  ANSI_X3.4-1968. 

I guess it is, it may just be me who missed something during the install

Comment: That's charmap of `export LANG=c`. Same with me.

Comment: When you `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, you get UTF-8, right?

Comment: Yes indeed ! Could it not be an issue with xterm itself, some kind of dark configuration necessary to handle unicode as well as UTF-8 ?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290439/220439)? I mean adding `for Powerline` after your font.

Comment: Nope, but it makes no difference, except from the font change.

Comment: Even with `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`?

Comment: Yep, sadly it doesn't work either

Comment: When you say: _Yes i do, hack is one of these._, do you mean you have that patched version from GitHub, not default one from repository?

Comment: Indeed, i downloaded/installed it from the powerline-fonts repo